# ANSI C - can a function returns another function?

Tags: function, ansi-c

I want to call a function and this function makes some calculations and returns another function pointer. Is that possible in `ANSI C` without creating `enum` function type? If so, how can i declare that function?

Comment: You want to return a `'function pointer'` from another function ?

Comment: yes something like that
[code] 
void (*anotherFunc) myFunc(int a) {
if(a<0) anotherFunc=adding;
else anotherFunc=multiplying;
return (anotherFunc);
}
[/code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to return a pointer to another function. The syntax for pointers is like `void (*myFuncPtr)(int)` where the myFuncPtr would be the variable name. Most probably you'd wanted to create a typedef to not type it all the time. A minimal example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int (*PUTS_PTR)(const char*);

PUTS_PTR ret_puts () {
    return puts;
}

int main () {
    PUTS_PTR pFunc = ret_puts();
    (*pFunc)("Hello");
}
```

You may also write the function pointer call just like `pFunc("Hello")` instead of `(*pFunc)("Hello");`. But in the second syntax there's less probability that you would forget to initialize or check the pointer.

Comment: That is what i want, in a different way of course. Thank you.